# TFS Check-In Over Server Version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs, version-control

How in TFS do you check-in a file over the server version (no matter what).

I see the option to Compare, Resolve, and revert local to the latest server version.
Where is the copy over server version option?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first check-out the file, modify it locally and check-in.

Comment: How do I check it out now that I have made changes. No menu option to do this.

Comment: Somehow I got the file as "not considered" part of the source. I +Add the file back, but because of its name... I still get name conflict and I'm unable to check it in. When I say undo pending changes. It un+Adds the files to source. Caught in a loop.